# If I do a lookup in a dictionary in pyspark code, will it be done on the cluster or on the main machine?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose I have a pyspark code which does some transformations on a data frame and the calls df.collect().

After calling df.collect(), I create a dictionary using python code and do a lookup on the values of that dictionary. Would that lookup be done on the cluster or on the master node?

The reason for asking this is, if the lookup is done on the master node then anytime I am faced with a dictionary that can be stored on the master node itself, it would be useless to create a broadcast variable of that dictionary. Since it won't be shipped to the clusters with tasks anyway. Or have I understood this whole thing incorrectly?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, but anything you do after `df.collect()` is done on the driver (master) node

Comment: @IslamElbanna you understood it correctly. I have a followup question to this. So in a case where I have a lookup dictionary that fits in my driver node, would it be beneficial to broadcast that dictionary or simply do the lookup after df.collect()?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest to distinguish between your environment/cluster components and pure Spark components. Executors and driver are Spark only components, when master/slave nodes belong to your cluster which consequently lives inside an environment, on-premise or on the cloud.

Everything that is computed after df.collect() happens on the driver. You can use broadcast along with anything that can be materialised and deserialised on the executor. These are all the entities supported by Spark i.e: array, map, dataframe. As you probably already know, when you broadcast some variable this is immediately available on every executor and it can be used during filtering, joining etc. so that we avoid redundant data movements, which accelerates the overall job execution.

As per your case, if the dictionary that you plan to broadcast, is created just after calling `df.collect()` then indeed it doesn't make sense to broadcast it since your job is already executed and has returned the results.

If you really need to involve Spark for the dictionary lookup, then I believe you need to modify your code accordingly in order to invoke the broadcast dictionary statement inside a Spark query. This is the only way to make sure the dictionary lookup takes place on the executors leveraging Spark parallel execution.